# Hooks not working in postgresql 9.3 when building from source

Tags: postgresql, hook

I need to use the hook feature of planner in postgresql 9.3 to perform a task. I am building postgresql from source.
To start with, I wanted to know how to create a hook and attach that shared libray to postgresql. Hence i tried the examples given in "wiki.postgresql.org/images/e/e3/Hooks_in_postgresql.pdf" and 
"https://github.com/gleu/Hooks-in-PostgreSQL/tree/master/examples/my_client_auth".

I have copied the "my_client_auth.c" file and Makefile into contrib/client_auth folder. make and make install is working fine.
This is the output of make install.

```
/bin/mkdir -p '/home/rajmohan/projects/lib/postgresql'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755  my_client_auth.so '/home/rajmohan/projects/lib/postgresql/'
```

after that i have added shared_preload_libraries = 'my_client_auth' to postgresql.conf.

When i rebuild and run the project and check client_auth_hook in postgresql code
client_auth_hook value is always zero. It seems my_client_auth.so file is not linked properly to my postgresql project.
Am i missing any step? how to access methods in my_client_auth.so from postgresql. Kindly help

Comment: What do you find in your log files?  Double-check your arguments to `install`; my docs say `-c` is ignored. Make sure permissions in your home directory permit what you *think* they permit.

Comment: thanks for ur reply. i gave make install in "/home/rajmohan/projects/postgresql-9.3.2/contrib/client_auth". the output is what i have posted in the question. How to check log?

Comment: I could not find any proper article online on how to add hook to postgresql when building from source. is there any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then i added the line ClientAuthentication_hook_type client_auth_hook = NULL; at the top of a file say planner.c

Why are you doing that?

If you want to use a hook from an extension, you must define a `_PG_init` function that sets the hook within the extension when it gets loaded at `shared_preload_libraries` time.

There is no need to modify the PostgreSQL source code its self. Only your extension. Take a look at the existing examples, like `contrib/auth_delay` in the PostgreSQL source tree, for how to do this correctly.

Your extension doesn't get "linked ... to the postgresql project" at compile/link time, either. It's a loadable module that PostgreSQL links to at runtime when you ask it to with `create extension` or by listing it in `shared_preload_libraries`. At that time it runs whatever code is in `_PG_init`, which is your opportunity to install hook functions etc.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Ya you are correct. I did not frame the qn properly earlier. I have a properly written hook file with _PG_init function and all. In the postgresql when I check the hook variable, I am not getting it to point to loaded library though I have given library_name.so file in shared_preload_libraries of postgresql.conf

Comment: @Rajmohan Add an `elog(ERROR, "My library loaded")` in your `_PG_init`.